# How to add focus on target input box (autocomplete search) after click the dropdwon list

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

this is input side

```
<input autofocus type="text" id="country_name" name="d1"  autocomplete="off" required size="5" tabIndex="1">
```

link with

```
<link href="library/bootstrap-5/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="library/bootstrap-5/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="library/autocomplete.js"></script>
```

How can i add focus the inputbox when this process done
autocomplete.js

```
this.field.nextSibling.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item').forEach((item) => {
          item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            let dataLabel = e.target.getAttribute('data-label');
            let dataValue = e.target.getAttribute('data-value');
    
            this.field.value = dataLabel;
    
            if (this.options.onSelectItem) {
              this.options.onSelectItem({
                value: dataValue,
                label: dataLabel
              });
            }
            
            //add focus on the inputbox
         
            this.dropdown.hide();
          })
```

Too many code,if you need i can email you

Comment: I would say there's opposite - too little code... :)  

First you're using arrow functions so `this` refers to the `this` in the outer scope...  
So I doubt your code works at all.

Comment: Please don't email anybody. Keeping the code and conversation on this page will help you and hopefully others too. For us to help you, create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can create a runnable snippet by editing the question. Look for the `<>` icon in the question editor.